# Finding an equivalent norm on $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the space $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ of complex, summable sequences. I'm searching for a norm on $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ which is equivalent to the standard $\ell^1$-norm. Is it possible to write down such a norm such that the unit ball in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ w.r.t. the new norm becomes strictly convex?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\tn}[1]{|\!|\!| #1|\!|\!|}$Recall that $\ell ^1\subseteq \ell ^2$, and that $\Vert x\Vert _2\leq \Vert x\Vert _1$,  for every $x$ in $\ell ^1$.  We may thus define a new  norm  on
$\ell ^1$ by
$$
  \tn x =   \Vert x\Vert _1 +  \Vert x\Vert _2,
  $$
and since
$$
  \Vert x\Vert _1 \leq  \tn x \leq  2\Vert x\Vert _1,
  $$
we see that $\tn \cdot $ is equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert _1$.

Finally, we claim that   $\tn \cdot $ is strictly convex.  To see this, suppose that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent
vectors in $\ell ^1$ such that $\tn x = \tn y = 1$.  Then
$$
  \tn{x+y} = \Vert x+y\Vert _1 +  \Vert x+y\Vert _2 \leq  $$$$ \leq 
  \Vert x\Vert _1 +  \Vert y\Vert _1 +  \Vert x+y\Vert _2 < $$$$ <
  \Vert x\Vert _1 +  \Vert y\Vert _1 +  \Vert x\Vert _2 +  \Vert y\Vert _2 \leq \tn x + \tn y,
  $$
where the strict inequality is due to the strict convexity of $\Vert \cdot \Vert _2$.  This proves that $\tn \cdot $ is strictly convex.